# Fix div to center of page, but don't overflow when resizing

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to make a navbar that fits the length of another div where I'm listing some data. I want it to be fixed to the top of the page no matter where you scroll. I have it like that, but when you resize the window from the right side and make it smaller, it'll eventually go off the page. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the fact that I'm translating it over 50% and it's not caring if it's going off screen, so is there some sort of way to easily counteract that? I'd like it to behave the way the table does. When it's about to go off screen, stop moving it over. Thanks for any help

Here is a demonstration:
http://box.endurehosting.com/contents/public/Screen-recorder-fri-jan-03-2020-21-31-14.webm

Here's the live website:
https://dev.theromdepot.com/archive.php?home

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div id="nav-bar">
<input id="search" placeholder="Search" type="input"></input>
</br>
</br>
    <div id="title-bar">
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Count</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS (I'm using SCSS)

```html
$mainBackground: #1d1f21;
$textHoverColor: #919191;

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Muli';
 src: url('../fonts/muli.ttf') format('truetype');
}

body {
    background-color:$mainBackground;
}

a {
 color:white;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: color .2s;
 &:hover {
  color:$textHoverColor;
  transition: color .2s;
 }
}

#nav-bar {
 position:fixed;
 width:25%;
 min-width:800px;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 background-color:grey;
 padding:10px;
 z-index:1;
 #search {
  &::placeholder {
   opacity:1;
  }
  position:relative;
  border:none;
  border-radius:2px;
  padding:5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 10px;
  &:focus {
   box-shadow:2px 2px 5px darkgrey;
  }
 }
 #title-bar{
  position:relative;
  color: white;
  p {
   display:inline-block;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: 600;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
 }
}

#list {
    margin:auto;
    width:25%;
    min-width:800px;
    color:white;
 #results {
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
  width:100%;
  .row {
   font-family: Muli;
   font-size: 14px;
   word-spacing: 2px;
      position:relative;
      width:100%;
      height:18px;
      padding-top:5px;
   p {
       display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    &:nth-child(1) {
     // left:5%;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
     left:51%;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
     left:67%;
    }
    &:nth-child(4) {
     margin:0;
     left:82.5%;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I now have it working thanks to Patrik Alexits. Heres what I did to get it to work. Just added this to my CSS:

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 #nav-bar{
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
 }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `min-width` property, which won't let it shrink under 800px. So when you are sizing the window down and passing 800px, the navbar stays the same width.

One solution could be using **media queries** in order when you reach the screen-width of 800pxs, you give the css property another value.

If that `min-width` attribute is not needed, since you are setting the `width`, you can just remove it and it will work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the great idea. It worked perfectly. I've edited my answer to show what I've done exactly for any future lurkers. Thank you so much